Cross Correlation for image sequence in time series
I am working on detecting movements in a time series image sequence using the cross-correlation method in Python. With a stable perspective from a ground-fixed camera, I aim to identify any sudden movements, specifically avalanches. The results will be represented as a heatmap overlayed on the last image in the sequence.
I've implemented a method to detect movements in a time series image sequence by calculating the cross-correlation for each pixel over time. I then store these values in a matrix with the same dimensions as the original images, normalize the values, and overlay them on the last image to create a heatmap. However, I'm encountering an issue where the heatmap displays a single color, despite selecting a sequence with movements. which means its wrong
Here's my code for calculating the cross-correlation:
def compute_cross_correlation(image_sequence):
       frames, height, width = image_sequence.shape
       cross_corr_map = np.zeros((height, width))

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            pixel_values = image_sequence[:, i, j]
            std = np.std(pixel_values)
            if std != 0:
                normalized_values = (pixel_values - np.mean(pixel_values)) / std
                cross_corr = np.correlate(normalized_values, normalized_values, mode='full')
                cross_corr_map[i, j] = np.max(np.abs(cross_corr))
            else:
                cross_corr_map[i, j] = np.nan

    return cross_corr_map


And here is the code for normalizing the result:
 def normalize_cross_corr(cross_corr_map):
        min_val = np.min(cross_corr_map)
        max_val = np.max(cross_corr_map)
        normalized_map = (cross_corr_map - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
        return normalized_map

Despite the implementation, the resulting heatmap is not displaying the expected variation and shows a unique color instead. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Update 01: based on @Anonymous comment, fixing the compute_cross_correlation(image_sequence)

Taking the maximum value of the cross-correlation but excluding the zero lag value
Assign zero if std is zero

    def compute_cross_correlation(image_sequence):
    frames, height, width = image_sequence.shape
    cross_corr_map = np.zeros((height, width))

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            pixel_values = image_sequence[:, i, j]
            mean = np.mean(pixel_values)
            std = np.std(pixel_values)
            
            if std != 0:
                normalized_values = (pixel_values - mean) / std
                cross_corr = np.correlate(normalized_values, normalized_values, mode='full')
                
                max_cross_corr = np.max(cross_corr[len(cross_corr) // 2 + 1:])
                cross_corr_map[i, j] = max_cross_corr
            else:
                cross_corr_map[i, j] = 0  

    return cross_corr_map


The issue is in your compute_cross_correlation function. You normalise the array by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. When you calculate the autocorrelation of that, the largest value (your output) will always be the length of the 1D array. You end up plotting either the number of your images, or np.nan.

pics (data) would be appreciated. -- we need a [mre]. without one, we can't even tell how you called your functions and how they truly relate. -- detecting avalances? optical flow would give you a vector for (almost) every pixel. it's not as sensitive as considering the entire picture though. for that, I'd recommend some other alignment procedure such as the "ECC" refinement in OpenCV. if you're fine with it taking a moment to calculate, you could use a picture every second instead of full frame rate video.

@Anonymous thanks for the responds, so what you saying i should calculate the mean before the if statement, and Take the maximum value of the cross-correlation but excluding the zero lag value, check Update 1

@ChristophRackwitz thanks for your answer my images are not taken from a video, there is a gap of 15 to 30min each frame, want to try optical flow, is it good to use patches or consider all patches, and also i will look into ECC and get back to you
